# CORDA Development

Tags: block, corda, chain

I need to implement CORDA Block Chain in our performance appraisal application which is developed in .Net Core and angular. Please guide us the structure and how to use it.
Your reply is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Kopal Rajpoot

Comment: Corda is built on Kotlin/Java (JVM), so you'd need to create a CorDapp and integrate your .NET application into it using HTTP, WebSockets, RabbitMQ, etc. I'd suggest you join the cordaledger slack channel to get started. https://slack.corda.net/

Answer (score 0):

So there's not a very clear question here, but if you're looking to get started with corda, here are some good links.

I'd recommend starting with the cordapp tutorial.

- https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/quickstart-deploy.html#running-the-example-cordapp
- corda documentation : https://docs.corda.net
- corda source code : https://github.com/corda/corda
- R3 developer slack : slack.corda.net we try to be very responsive there.

good luck!